# Not able to view SDCard folder in the FileExplorer of Android Eclipse

Tags: android

I am not able to view SDCard folder in FileExplorer of DDMS in Android.
But I was able to view SDCard folder when I used adb command from command prompt like below:

```
androidsdk\tools>adb shell
$ ls
```

I am able to view list of folders when I typed ls in which I can see sdcard folder from the list of folders .my doubt how can we view the sdCard option in Eclipse using FileExplorer.Also I want I want to delete or insert some files in sdcard.How can this be possible for me.can anyone hel me in sorting out this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use it as mass storage device for transferring data.

Comment: sdcard is usually mounted under /mnt/sdcard folder. look for /mnt/sdcard instead of /sdcard.

Comment: But when I click fileExplorer, I am able to view only 2 folders, data and System. I did not find mant folder too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem:

Using Eclipse DDMS File Explorer the content of sdcard was not visible in any folder (CyanogenMod with Android 4.2.2).

The solution was:
On the device you have to give ADB root access. Here: Settings / Developer options / Root access

Then the content of sdcard is visible in this folder:
/mnt/shell/emulated/0

Answer (score 1):

You can download Astro file explorer from marketplace to do this. It is free.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into **/mnt/sdcard** folder instead of **/sdcard**. I had the same problem.